# Destroy Session with Prefix

Tags: php, session, session-variables

In my site, all Sessions are start with '**KarSho_**'. See Below,

```
array(2) {
  ["KarSho_session_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["KarSho_session_username"]=>
  string(5) "admin"
}
```

I want to destory my Session variable, which is starting with 'KarSho_'.

How I can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// by using `foreach` and   `strpos`

> `foreach($_SESSION)` loop get you all session variable you need to
>   check session key having a prefix  KarSho_. To match string use
>   strpos.

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
if (strpos($key, 'KarSho_') === 0)
{
unset($_SESSION[$key]); 
}
}
```

Comment: Uh, I hope nobody will ask what this code does, because you don't explain it.